# How can I control what symbols are exported from a shared library in Bazel?

Tags: c++, gcc, ld, bazel

I'm learning Bazel, because I have to use it at work. I have a simple build rule that creates a library from a single file and I would like control what is exported by the linker by using a linker version file. (I'm on Linux)

So I tried:

```
cc_library (
    name ="thelib",
    srcs = ["lib.cpp"],
    linkopts = ["-Wl,--version-script,lib.ver"]
)
```

And it tells me "No such file or directory".

What have I tried:

- I tried a path relative to the directory I issue the bazel build command with no avail.
- cc_library()'s documentation says "linkopts" support make variable substitution so I listed the make variables with `bazel info --show_make_env` it showed me a variable called `workspace`
  so I then tried `$(workspace)/lib/lib.ver` but then it says `$(workspace) not defined` so Bazel is a liar.
- The only thing that works is spelling the absolute path to the linker script but I don't want to push that.
- cc_library() has a win_def_file option but guess what, that's Windows only.
- A [self-closed github issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4440) suggests that I should pass the filename as a separate argument, it doesn't work either.
- Using `-fvisiblity=hidden` and export using `__attribute__` to export is not an option because the standard C++ library overrides it and forces exporting of the symbols you don't want to appear on the interface (the library is used using extern "C" interface only I don't want any other garbage appear on it).
- There doesn't seem to be an option in Bazel to specify the symbols to export natively.

At this point I completely ran out of ideas. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, shared libraries are generally declared with `cc_binary` in conjunction with its `linkshared` attribute rather than `cc_library`. This is counterintuitive but reflects the intention that `cc_binary` creates a transitive link while `cc_library` declares an intermediate library. (More adventurous folks may try out [`cc_shared_library`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/master/examples/experimental_cc_shared_library.bzl.)

Second of all, it's possible to use version scripts (and other linker scripts) by using them in `linkopts` and declaring them as a dependency in `deps`.

So, all together:

```py
cc_binary(
   name = 'mylib.so',
   linkshared = True,
   srcs = ['mylib.cc'],
   linkopts = ['-Wl,-version-script=$(location version-script.lds)'],
   deps = [
      'version-script.lds',
   ]
)
```

Comment: I tried this and got two errors: first Bazel wants me to use .ld, .lds or .ldscript file extensions in the deps section. Second: gcc complains about undefined reference to main so it tries to make an executable not a shared object. If I rename lib.ver to lib.ld and use cc_library then I can get the shared object I want.

Comment: Strange, but in the project where I wanted to add the version script to they use cc_binary and that creates a shared object for them. I have no idea of what is happening... I guess I'll pull all my hair out while I'm on this project.

Comment: I think the missing element is setting `linkshared = True`, which I forgot to mention the first time.